# Python: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Tags: python, file, text, replace

I am trying to copy text from `mobileBuildSettings` and use it to replace text from `abproject`. I am getting the following error and I don't understand it.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'
```

Below is my code:

```
with open("C:/abproject.build", "r+") as script, open ("C:/tempfile.build","w+") as newscript:
abproject = ("C:/abproject.build")
for line in abproject.readlines():
    if line == "@AppIdentifier@" :
        newabproject.write('"' + "AppIdentifier : " + '"' + appIdentifier.get() + '"' + "\n")
    else:
        newabproject.write(line)
abproject.close()
newabproject.close()
os.remove("abproject.txt")
os.remove("tempfile.buil","abproject.txt")
```

Comment: `abproject` is a string. Do `script.readlines()` not `abproject.readlines()`

Comment: The error tells you that `abproject` is a string. The String class doesn't have a method called `readlines()`. What do you want to do with the parentheses around `"C:/abproject.build"`?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thank you that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to give a good answer to jill1993's question and take the MosesKoledoye's answer :

```
abproject = ("C:/abproject.build")
```

`abproject` is a string object. Furthermore, you write :

```
with open("C:/abproject.build", "r+") as script
```

So if you want to solve your script error, you have to write :

```
with open("C:/abproject.build", "r+") as script, open ("C:/tempfile.build","w+") as newscript:
abproject = ("C:/abproject.build")
for line in script.readlines():
    if line == "@AppIdentifier@" :
        newscript.write('"' + "AppIdentifier : " + '"' + appIdentifier.get() + '"' + "\n")
    else:
        newscript.write(line)
script.close()
newscript.close()
os.remove("abproject.txt")
os.remove("tempfile.buil","abproject.txt")
```

And your script should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
for line in abproject.readlines():
```

to:

```
for line in script.readlines():
```